# Extracting specific rows from csv files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io

I have files containing raw signals. The files start with the first column being 'time' and the second being the 'signal'.

There are about 8 million lines due to the fact that the time span is of about 20 hours with the time in increments of 10 ms.

I am wanting to extract specific chunks of data from the files at various 'start' and 'stop' times.

I managed to get something going. This is my code:

```
import csv

#Constructs arrays of length 500 ms from raw signals
def constructor(filename, new_file, start, stop, label):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fileRead:
        reader = csv.reader(fileRead, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if float(row[0]) == float(start):
                while float(row[0]) != float(stop):
                    array = []
                    for i in range(50):
                        array.append(row[1])
                        row = next(reader)
                    with open(new_file, 'ab') as fileWrite:
                        array.append(label)
                        writer = csv.writer(fileWrite)
                        writer.writerow(array)
            else:
                continue

constructor('SC4001E0-PSG_FPZ-CZ.csv', 'new.csv', 0, 1, 0)
constructor('SC4001E0-PSG_FPZ-CZ.csv', 'new.csv', 30630, 30750, 1)
```

The 'start' and 'stop' times are in seconds.

0 being at time '0', 360 being at the '6 minute' mark, so on and so forth.

I am wanting to run through the data and group the data in epochs of half a second, hence the `for i in range(50)` part, AND write this list to another csv file.

My code 'technically' works. If I start my program to begin at start = 0 and stop = 0.5, from my data file:

```
0       5.01685
0.01    -2.578755
0.02    1.359707
0.03    -2.391209
0.04    -5.204396
0.05    -7.454945
0.06    -8.298901
0.07    -6.892308
0.08    -3.704029
0.09    -0.984615
0.1     2.203663
0.11    2.016117
0.12    1.641026
0.13    -2.672527
0.14    -0.79707
0.15    1.359707
0.16    2.860073
0.17    -2.203663
0.18    0.515751
0.19    5.860806
0.2     -1.734799
0.21    -3.047619
0.22    2.860073
0.23    7.830037
0.24    2.953846
0.25    -0.984615
0.26    -1.922344
0.27    -6.704762
0.28    -7.548718
0.29    -4.829304
0.3     -12.612454
0.31    -9.23663
0.32    -12.331136
0.33    -8.298901
0.34    -16.36337
0.35    -21.145788
0.36    -23.677656
0.37    -21.23956
0.38    -20.208059
0.39    -23.771429
0.4     -26.115751
0.41    -25.646886
0.42    -26.115751
0.43    -26.678388
0.44    -22.8337
0.45    -22.458608
0.46    -21.520879
0.47    -16.644689
0.48    -16.082051
0.49    -11.393407
```

I get this:

```
5.01685 -2.578755   1.359707    -2.391209   -5.204396   -7.454945   -8.298901   -6.892308   -3.704029   -0.984615   2.203663    2.016117    1.641026    -2.672527   -0.79707    1.359707    2.860073    -2.203663   0.515751    5.860806    -1.734799   -3.047619   2.860073    7.830037    2.953846    -0.984615   -1.922344   -6.704762   -7.548718   -4.829304   -12.612454  -9.23663    -12.331136  -8.298901   -16.36337   -21.145788  -23.677656  -21.23956   -20.208059  -23.771429  -26.115751  -25.646886  -26.115751  -26.678388  -22.8337    -22.458608  -21.520879  -16.644689  -16.082051  -11.393407  0
```

Which is EXACTLY what I want BUT sometimes my 'start' and 'stop' time can vary greatly. If I run the `constructor('SC4001E0-PSG_FPZ-CZ.csv', 'new.csv', 30630, 30750, 1)` line of code... Nothing happens. It's as if the Python script GAVE up due to the start time being so far away.

The reason why I run the functions, cascaded the way I have it, is because all the different chunks of data I need at the varying times. All these chunks of data have their corresponding label.

Data of range 240s to 350s, could be label 2.
Data of range 56000s to 62130s could be label 1, etc. I want all these lists, or epochs, with their corresponding label on a new csv file.

I understand that with each run of the function, at a 'start' time so big, would mean that the function starts to do a bit of a redundant process, having to reopen and reread the data file from the beginning.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Does anyone know why the script stops at large 'start' times?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I found out my error. It happened to be 100% user error. The reason why my script did not extract rows at further `start` values, was because there was NO data there to begin with. My files are so large, that Excel chopped off the remaining data from the file after Excel hit its limit.

Besides very few additions and changes to my code, it works great. So if anyone wants to use it as a reference, there it is.

Comment: I think you're simply jumping your `stop` value: you have a `for` loop iterating through the next 50 lines; what happens if your `stop` value is in those 50 lines? If with `30650` as `start` value and `30750` as `stop` value it works, it's because you're skipping the value. You can fix this by setting the `while` condition as `<=` instead of `!=`

Comment: Well remember that each row, or line, in my data, is actually a hundredth of a second. So 100 lines would equal a full 1 second. So like in my could above, if i set `start` to 0 and `stop` to 1, I would end up with two lists. I tried your suggestion though, it didn't work :/.

Comment: Did you tried start = 30650 and stop = 30750?

Comment: Yea, nothing... It's as if since the `start` is so far out and it has to check every single `row[0]`, which is the time, that it just doesn't bother and gives up. The ONLY way I am able to make it work is adding a `print row[0]` right after `for row in reader` because this way, it gives the script 'something' to do until it reaches the `start` time to start extracting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
import csv

#Constructs arrays of length 500 ms from raw signals
def constructor(filename, new_file, start, stop, label):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f_input, open(new_file, 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        block = []

        for row in takewhile(lambda r: float(r[0]) < stop, dropwhile(lambda r: float(r[0]) < start, csv_input)):
            if len(block) == 50:
                csv_output.writerow(block + [label])
                block = []
            block.append(row[1])

        # This would write any remaining entries but label would not be in the same column
        csv_output.writerow(block + [label])   

constructor('input.csv', 'new1.csv', 0.0, 1.0, 0)
constructor('input.csv', 'new2.csv', 30630.0, 30750.0, 1)
```

This makes use of `itertools.dropwhile()` and `itertools.takewhile()` to first filter out the rows that are of interest. Next it appends the values until 50 are reached and then writes the block to the output file.

Note, the final `.writerow()` will output any remaining values. As `label` is appended, it might not be in the same column. I would recommend making your label the first column, e.g. `[label] + block`

Comment: Thank you for the help!. I heard about `itertools`so I will try it out as well. It turns out that the reason why my script was not working, was because there was missing data from the data file that the script was trying to access. So it was completely user error.